# I am getting 405 error after submitting form in spring.This Only happens in certain cases

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting a 405 error, I have added try catches and couldn't find any error in the log.
I have added some logs and could see that the code is executing till one point and then a warning message come up.

```
URL file = new URL("get the url"); 

BufferedImage image;
image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

**(the code executes till here after that warning message displayed in the log)**

```
BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH, 1000, 1000);
```

**WARN [http-apr-8081-exec-96] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver (DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:215) Request method 'POST' not supported**

What could be the issue?

Comment: 405 is "method not supported" which your warning message also indicates.  At a guess you are sending a post request to an endpoint designed for a different http access method.

Comment: It looks like your form POSTs the request to the webserver but the webserver is unable to handle it and it is telling you back that a POST is not supported. It cannot find a suitable handler for it. I would recheck the controller which needs to handle this request, how it is defined and try to do changes such that you manage to hit the controller once you POST.